# how to make sure dots in the slideshow forms are after the forms instead of sitting on the labels and textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on making a slideshow of forms. Here is my working [codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwJWRQ). As you can see I have two dots on the right side which if I click then it opens another form. Only thing is those dots are just sitting on the right side labels and texbox and that I don't want it.

For example as shown in this [image](https://postimg.org/image/4isaog1mx/). I am trying to replicate exactly like this image and as you can see those dots are on the form instead but at the very right side of it close to the right border but not lying on the labels and texbox. `LAST NAME`, `PHONE NUMBER` , `PROVINCE` and `CITY` label and its textbox are just before those dots. I want to do something similar. How can I make sure those forms are just above those dots not lying on them. I tried playing with form width but it is moving those dots as well along with it. Also I want to make dots color to orange if it is on that form (just like in the image I have). As of now it shows black.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- End CSS for slidesjs.com example -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Optional: If you'd like to use this design -->
  <style>
    body {
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      font: normal 15px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #232525;
    }

    #slides,
    #slides2,
    #slides3 {
      display: none;
      margin-bottom:50px;
    }

    .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url("https://s16.postimg.org/pt4k43i9x/pagination.png");
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }
  </style>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Optional-->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: These styles are required if you'd like a responsive slideshow -->
  <style>
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto
    }

    /* For tablets & smart phones */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
      }
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smartphones */
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
      .container {
        width: auto
      }
    }

    /* For smaller displays like laptops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .container {
        width: 724px
      }
    }

    /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
   <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
               <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
         <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
         <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>  
  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
   <h3>INSURANCE FORM</h3>
   <h4><i>BASIC DETAILS</i></h4>
   <br>    
    <div id="slides" class="container-fluid" >
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 1">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>FIRST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="Mickey 2">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>LAST NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="Mouse">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>EMAIL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="abc@host.com">
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>PHONE NUMBER</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="123-456-789">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label>COUNTRY</label>
            <select name="country" class="form-control">
               <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>PROVINCE</label>
            <select name="province" class="form-control">
               <option value="ontario">ONTARIO</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>CITY</label>
            <select name="city" class="form-control">
               <option value="ottawa">OTTAWA</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });

      /*
        To have multiple slideshows on the same page
        they just need to have separate IDs
      */
      $('#slides2').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false,
        start: 3,
        play: {
          auto: true
        }
      });

      $('#slides3').slidesjs({
        width: 800,
        height: 528,
        navigation: false
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps some `padding-right`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do following three things to fix this

First Solution.

- Increase the padding of container from 10 to 20px. sothat dots will remain at right side and some will create between form and dots.

Second Solution

- Make Dots fixed with respect to screen, I think dots will always show on screen, not movable and after reduce the width of form from 100% to some less around 95%;

Third Solution

- Just reduce width of form to 95%.
- Provide right padding more than 10px.

Comment: I see.. which one do you recommend? can you provide codegen link as well for demonstration so that I can make sure it works?

Comment: Well, It depends on your requirement, if i recommend i will go for second one as dots should be visible always. I can show you on codepen for this if you want.

Comment: So for second solution how can I do that? You mean just reduce the form width that's it?

Comment: bcoz if I change the form width to let's say 80% then mostly it looks good but city drop down is not aligned with last name and phone number and it is going away. take a look at [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwJWRQ) you will get an idea?

Comment: You have reduced width of inputs fields don't do that. Apply width to 'slidesjs-container' class. and remove width from input that you have applied.

Comment: You mean this one `#slides`? if yes then it doesnt work either, it moves dots along with it.

Comment: First child of its. having class "slidesjs-container"